# Cross-product of a vector with a bivector?

Tags: geometry, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I am interested in understanding the physical/geometric meaning of the cross-product between a vector $v$ and a bi-vector $b$.

---

To help me understand better I have investigated a physical example. Let us take an example using $Cl_{3,1}$, with $v$ and $b$ defined as:

$$
v=t\gamma_0+x\gamma_1+y\gamma_2+z\gamma_3\\
b=E_x\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_y\gamma_0\gamma_2+E_z\gamma_0\gamma_2+B_xi\gamma_0\gamma_1+B_yi\gamma_0\gamma_2+B_zi\gamma_0\gamma_3
$$

Now I will take the geometric product of $u=v+b$:

$$
u^2=v^2+b^2+vb+bv
$$

We now find a physical/geometric interpretation for each term:

1. $v^2=t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$, which is the square of the interval of special
   relativity.
2. $b^2=E_x^2+E_y^2+E_z^2-B_x^2-B_y^2-B_z^2+2i(E_xB_x+E_yB_y+E_zB_z)$, which are the invariants of electromagnetism.
3. But what about the term $vb+bv$?

After a couple of pages of algebra, I identify the term $vb+bv$ as:

$$
vb+bv=2\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2(yF_x-xF_y)+2\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_3(zF_x-F_xz)+2\gamma_0\gamma_2\gamma_3(yF_z-F_zy)
$$

where $F_x=E_x+iB_x$, $F_y=E_y+iB_y$, $F_z=E_z+iB_z$.

Now if I flip $\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_3$ to $\gamma_0\gamma_3\gamma_1$ then I simply obtain the cross-product between the space components of $v$ and the electromagnetic field.

$$
u^2=v^2+b^2+i v(x,y,z)\times b
$$

---

I was not able to find any references in the physics literature regarding the cross product between position and electromagnetic field. So I am at a loss of what it could mean physically or geometrically. Can someone help me understand the meaning of the cross-product between a vector and a bi-vector?

Comment: That's actually a wedge product: $vb+bv=2v\wedge b=2\langle vb\rangle_3$, resulting in a trivector. If we assume $b$ is simple (having the form $c\wedge d$, representing the plane of the vectors $c$ and $d$), then we get $2v\wedge c\wedge d$, which represents an oriented volume, a parallelepiped with edges $2v,c,d$ (or $v,2c,d$ or $v,c,2d$). Alternatively, it represents the 3D subspace itself, spanned by $v,c,d$ in the 4D space. If $b$ is not simple (having the form $c\wedge d+c'\wedge d'$, not contained in a plane), there is no obvious geometric interpretation.

Comment: I think your expansion of $vb+bv$ is wrong; it includes trivectors multiplied by $i=\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3$, resulting in vectors, while it should be only trivectors. Perhaps you assumed that $i$ commutes with everything.

Comment: Anyway, I don't know what you know about geometric algebra, but maybe you'll find something helpful here: http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/html/Intro.html